# Custom WPF Control to add an int property to TextBox

Tags: c#, wpf, custom-controls

I would like an additional WPF control that would add an `int` property to the TextBox class. I have tried Project > Add New Item > Custom Control (WPF). That gave me a new cs file for the new Control. I tried just having this new class inherit `TextBox` class and then adding `public int number { get; set; }` inside `static CustomTextBox()` but apparently that is not the correct syntax.

The `TextBox`s I need this for are to be created dynamically in code, not in XAML.

Here is my attempt at implementing [John Gardner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13687/john-gardner)'s answer:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty Number = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
        "number",
        typeof(TextBox),
        typeof(int),
        new PropertyMetadata(false)
        );
    public static void SetNumber(UIElement element, TextBox value)
    {
        element.SetValue(Number, value);
    }
    public static TextBox GetNumber(UIElement element)
    {
        return (TextBox)element.GetValue(Number);
    }
```

I added this in the MainWindow Class. It does not appear to give my `TextBox`s the additional Number property.

Comment: Making a very simple subclass of TextBox should do what you want - or did you solve the problem already?

Comment: Still trying to implement John's answer and open to other solutions. How would I make a subclass of TextBox?

Comment: Ok - have posted a suggestion as an answer..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just create a subclass of TextBox and add a single int property to it. That should do it I guess.

Take a look at this code to see an example of how to do it:

```
public partial class Window1 : Window
{
    public Window1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        panel.Children.Add(new MyTextBox { Number = 123 });
        panel.Children.Add(new MyTextBox { Number = 321 });
        panel.Children.Add(new MyTextBox { Number = 456 });
        panel.Children.Add(new MyTextBox { Number = 654 });
    }

    private void click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var myTextBoxes = panel.Children.OfType<MyTextBox>();
        var numbers = string.Empty;
        myTextBoxes.ToList().ForEach(p => numbers += p.Number + Environment.NewLine);
        MessageBox.Show(numbers);
    }
}

//Subclass of TextBox that just adds one property
public class MyTextBox : TextBox
{
    public int Number { get; set; }
}
```

..and the XAML just has the panel and a button:

```
<StackPanel Name="panel">
    <Button Content="Show numbers" Click="click" />
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: Simple, and it does exactly what I was looking for. Thanks.

Comment: yes, you technically *can* do this, but there are lots of reasons you might not want to.  You could later have styling issues (you have a new control), if you want to use it in xaml you now need local namespace and such in your xaml `<local:MyTextBox/>`, etc. the attached property direction allows you to add number support to any textbox you can get ahold of programmatically, too.

Answer (score 1):

Do you *need* a new control?  You might be better off using an attached property instead.  then no new control at all.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc265152(v=VS.95).aspx

**Update:** 
an attached property doesn't add a property to the textbox directly, you'd access it like

```
YourClass.SetNumber( textbox, value );
int value = YourClass.GetNumber( textbox );
```

or in xaml,

```
    <TextBox YourClass.Number="1"/>
```

your property should be "Number" in its string definition as well, you have "number".  And your Get/Set calls should have an int value, not a textbox.

Comment: I don't necessarily need a new control, just the described functionality. I have added an example of my attempted implementation of your answer to the question.

Comment: Still trying to get this. I have moved the DependencyProperty stuff into its own class outside of Main, but when I try to call SetNumber, it throws an error: {"Default value type does not match type of property 'Number'."} I have cast all my numbers as Int32s.

Comment: is that because of your `new PropertyMetaData(false)` ?  I think it should be either `new PropertyMetaData(0)` or `new PropertyMetaData()` or null?